# Getting Duplicate entry java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am getting the duplicate entry issue at runtime if I add the intercom library to my gradle.

This is my total app gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        disable "ResourceType"
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a","x86"
    }
    applicationId "com.sample.activities"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    multiDexEnabled true
}
dexOptions {

    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

productFlavors {
    with_ImageProcessor {
    }
    without_ImageProcessor {

    }
}

}
 configurations {
}






dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.1'

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'


configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core'
}


compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.0.1'

compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.2'


//for intercom

compile 'io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-fcm:4.+'


compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.1'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'
compile 'com.uncopt:android.justified:1.0'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.0.1'


   }
   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

i am getting this issue afetr adding this line

```
 compile 'io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-fcm:4.+'
```

This is the run Time error I am getting

Error:Execution failed for task':waleteros:transformClassesWithJarMergingForWith_ImageProcessorDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzbax.class

Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: have you enabled multidexing?

Comment: please read error`java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:` @R.R.M i don't think its a multidex problem

Comment: @gowthami can you please show your full build.gradle file of app module?

Comment: Why are you having 2 `com.android.support:design` remove 26.0.1.Clean and sync after removing 26.0.1

Comment: I added total app gradle @Mr Narendra

Comment: @gowthami try updating the versions of all firebase and gms dependencies to `11.0.4`

Answer (score 2):

Try to add following version of intercom library instead of version you are using :

```
 compile 'io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-fcm:4.0.0'
```

OR

```
 compile 'io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-fcm:4.0.4'
```

Comment: Thats Great (Y)

Comment: That sounds great :)

Comment: Please mark it as right if it helped you. So that others can find it easily.